# Cells in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am trying to parse a pdf using PyPDF2 in a Jupyter notebook. Below is how I would like to write the different parts of the code, that is, the extract text statements in one cell and the RegEx in a new cell. However, if I separate the two pieces of code as below, the RegEx only runs through the last page of the file and not through the whole file (12 pages). Why does this happen? I would really like to use different cells.

```
import PyPDF2
import re

file = open(r'file.pdf', 'rb')
doc = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
#print(doc.getNumPages())
```

#new cell

```
for i in range(0, 12):
page = doc.getPage(i)
text = page.extractText()
   #print(text)
```

#new cell

```
doc_re = re.compile(r'S\d+_\d+', re.IGNORECASE)
result = doc_re.findall(text)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you run your `for` loop, you're resetting the value of text by using `text = page.extractText()`

The RegEx is running on what you give it, which is `text`. Even though your loop runs over 12 pages, the second cell of code receives the final value of `text` (which is whatever you assign it to be on the last iteration of the loop).

You can either move the code from your second cell inside of your for loop, or a better option would be to add each page's text to text.

So, turning `text =` into `text +=` should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, PntButterWolf. One thing I got stuck on now (I'm a beginner) is that if I use 'text +=' , each time I run the for loop the output is appended, ie, the first time I run the cell 'text' = 12 pages long, the second time 'text' = 24 pages and so on... How can I stop it from appending the output? 'text' should always be 12 pages regardless of how many times I rerun the cell.

Comment: @SR-77 the annoying thing about Jupyter is that it doesn't reset your variables after you finish executing a cell (this is so you can use that computed variable in later cells in your notebook).In the same cell, after getting your output with `print`, delete / reset your `text` variable. That will clear the slate for the next run of your cell

Comment: thanks for the advice. I'm very close to finishing my first Python project! Yay!